# Couldnot retrieve data from firebase realtime database

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, observable, angularfire2

I am a beginner of angular. While i tried to retrieve data using AngularFireDatabase object, i am not getting the  data in the required format

Interface:

```
export interface AppUser {
name: string;
email: string;
isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

Function call:

```
 get appUser$():Observable<AppUser>{
 return this.user$.pipe(
  map(user=> this.userService.get(user.uid)))
}
```

userService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject} from  angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { AppUser } from './models/app-file';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

get (uid : string){
let result={};
this.userdetails = this.db.object('/users/'+uid).valueChanges();
return this.userdetails;

}
```

ERROR in src/app/auth.service.ts(40,6): error TS2322: Type 'Observable>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  Type 'Observable' is missing the following properties from type 'AppUser': name, email, isAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your core functionality, for example, getting data from the database, your auth guards should be in a separate module. I Use to call it Core Module. I'm writing this because you have mentioned that you are a beginner.
So for this case, nn your service file do this:

```
getDataFromDb(uid) {
 return this.db.object('/users/'+ uid).valueChanges();
}
```

The method is just getting the data under users' node from firebase. The method `valueChanges()` it self returns an observable of type `Observable<any[]>`

Now inside your component's ts file, you should subscribe to that observable and assert that value to whatever type or interface you have defined.

and in your ts file:

```
export class Component() {

result: AppUser;

 constructor(private service: Service) {}


dataFromService() {
 this.userService.getDataFromDb(user.uid).subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.result = res;
  })
 }
}
```

What you are currently doing in you ts file is that you are using `map` operator which would not emit the value unless you subscribe to it. And in your case, you don't even have to use `pipe`. Just use `subscribe` to get the value form the observable. Read the docs for better understanding:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md

Comment: still having the error "ERROR in src/app/auth.service.ts(41,6): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Subscription>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<AppUser>'.
  Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'AppUser': name, email, isAdmin"

Comment: ts file : get appUser$():Observable<AppUser>{
   
      return this.user$.pipe(
        map(user=>  this.userService.get(user.uid).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
       })))

}